# Bridged pc pc network in sleepmode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, bridge, ps4

I have bridged the lan and wifi conections on my desktop, and i'm trying to figure out how to keep this bridge active while the desktop is in sleep mode. Any ideas? In case it's relevant, im using a Belkin wireless usb adapter.

The reason why i'm trying to figure this out is because my ps4 is conected to my desktop with lan, and is usinge the wireles adapter.

Sorry for my por english grammer, it's my third language.

Comment: Which desktop PC component(s) would you expect to perform the bridging activities while it is in sleep mode? Because there are none available.

Comment: The bridge is allredy on and working. The bridge is between my wifi card and the lan port, so that it can provide internet to my ps4. The problem is that when my pc goes into sleep mode, it disconects from the wifi, and therfore my ps4 loses it's connection.

Comment: @liptonvice One thing you can try is going to your device manager in Windows, right click on each network adapter (wireless and Ethernet) go to the last tab 'power management' and turn all power management off. This should stop them from going to sleep however if Windows is sleeping I doubt it will route traffic.

Comment: @liptonvice You didn't understand. There is no hardware bridge in your PC. It would require a kind of DMA master controller with routing abilities which still has power while the rest of the system is sleeping. There is no such thing in any consumer PC. "The bridge" is nothing but software, so if your main processor sleeps, then there is no bridge.

Comment: Ok, i see, my bad. I guess i will have to settel for not having it in sleep mode. Thank's for the help @Class Stacker.

Answer (score 0):

There is **NOT Possible** with the described topology:

**And it's simple:**

The [Network Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) or [Wireless Adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_network_interface_controller) are managed by the operating system. When you put your system in [Sleep Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode) is like paused, and basically your system saves a stage in RAM to be able to recover it later, your computer lost the ability to manage those devices.

***My Suggestion:***

Get an [Layer 3 Networking Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28computing%29) to provide Internet to all your desired devices in your network.